# how to automatically update one table column by another table column update in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, schema

I have a WALLET table with a Balance Column & I have a PAYMENT table with a Price Column I want to automatically the WALLET BALANCE Column update When the PAYMENT PRICE Column is updated or NEW PAYMENT is Created.
What Should I Do?

Comment: a `trigger` might be applicable and suitable for your needs? [mySQL Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: since balance is a derived column then usually you should not be storing it in the database but calculating it when you need it based on the transactions. If there's a real performance reason you don't want to do this then triggers might do the trick but just keep in mind this is how you open the doors to data inconsistencies and if you are handling actual currency you might instead want to take the peformance hit rather than risk people losing money out of nothing (or gaining money in which case you'd have to cover the difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel you can use `Observers`, please see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers)

observer code sample:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Payment;

class PaymentObserver
{
    public function created(Payment $payment)
    {
        $wallet = $payment->wallet;
        $wallet->balance = $payment->price;
        $wallet->save();
    }

    public function updated(Payment $payment)
    {
        if($payment->wasChanged('price')){
            $wallet = $payment->wallet;
            $wallet->balance = $payment->price;
            $wallet->save();
        }
        
    }
}
```